# How do I increase the sensitivity of a CNN autoencoder for anomaly detection, when my dataset contains mostly zero values?

Tags: machine-learning, fft, autoencoder

I am learning to use autoencoders for anomaly detection. I am using the model provided on the keras website, with data that I have created. My ‘correct data’ used for training the model is a single frequency sine wave with random amplitudes and my ‘anomaly data’ used for testing the model is the original data, with a sine wave of a different frequency superimposed.

In the time domain the model works very well. However, in the frequency domain (I did a fft), because the data is almost all zeros with either 1 or 2 nonzero values, the sensitivity of the loss function to these data points is extremely low. The model is ultimately able to detect the different between the correct data and the anomalies with 100% precision but the loss is near 0 in all cases. If we had a scenario where instead of the non-dominant frequencies being 0, they were simply a small number, the ML model would surely have no chance of making the correct prediction. Please see the following graphs

[Example of correct data + prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhJTu.jpg)

[Example of anomaly data + prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCeRu.jpg)

[Histogram of predictions, showing clear separation into 2 group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvIQd.jpg)

What can I do to make my model loss more sensitive to the desired data? One idea I have is to remove the zero data. However, this means that my input data length is not fixed. I don’t even know if the CNN- can handle this. I don’t want to switch to an LSTM as the convolution is important to me so that the network can handle various frequencies without being explicitly trained on those frequencies.

What other options do I have? Perhaps a loss function which can give higher importance to these values? I do understand that if  have noisy data I can clean it but I am still concerned that it will not insufficient for less 'black and white' scenarios.